# browsers add an inherent inner padding on div/span, trying to trim text but

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a plugin to trim text from an element container. 
Basically, I am just taking the length of the text - enclosing it in span, hiding it and detecting the point at which the length of the text can fit in a different container.

1. have parent container, lets say it has a width of 200px.
2. I create a temp 'span', put text in... detect width.
   i. I chomp off the last character, retest - once the text can fit within 200pix.. great.

BUT, the text I am left with is about 5 or so characters too short. Meaning, I 'could' fit more characters in it.

Do browsers add a padding or something in which it would throw my width() detection off?

I am using this as the temp container:

```
temp = $('<span>',{ text: sampletext })
 .css({'position': 'absolute','float': 'left', 'font': setfont, 'visibility': 'hidden',
       'white-space': 'nowrap'})
 .appendTo($('body')),
```

Comment: What's the original container? Make the temp span have the exact same (computed) css properties as the parent

Comment: For the sake of argument, are you sure that the parent container doesn't have padding that makes it look like there's more space than there is?

Comment: yeah, I checked for the parent if it had padding - it doesn't. but let me try what bfaretto suggests.. I'll just copy over the parent containers properties. Perhaps I wasn't clear. I grab the parent container width() -- then test against that.